# NativeScript: QR Code disappearing on resizing CMD window

Tags: nativescript

I am using nativescript for building a sample android app for my android device. The problem comes when scanning the QR code generated from the `tns preview` command. After resizing the `CMD` window, the QR code disappears. To be able to regenerate, I have to close the `CMD` window and start all over again. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Just change the terminal - I am using the VSCode build-in terminal with both bash and CMD and this is not an issue there.

Comment: @NickIliev I forgot to mention in my post but yes I am also using VSCode and have seen the built in terminal...I will give that a try